# Peer not authenticated - Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

This happens for my Android Studio 2.1.1. I haven't made changes in my code. It just shows me this error. I have tried solutions that I have found in StackOverflow but nothing works.
My build script is like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
```

Comment: parse is shutting down, isn't it? they haven't renewed their certificate.

Comment: Are you behind any kind of firewall?

Comment: No, I am not behind a firewall.

Comment: muratgu, yes, Parse is shutting down. It will be open-source. How can I use Parse in the future? Maybe I should ask it in Parse forum on Github.

Comment: don't use parse, use firebase. look it up.

Comment: Thanks. But I have already an app which has used Parse and has a lot of users. So I cannot move it to Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in Parse forum https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/463:

> This seems to be an issue with Parse's Gradle plugin, which is not
>   part of Parse-Android-SDK, so I'll be closing this issue. In either
>   case, Parse is shutting down their services so I wouldn't be surprised
>   if they stop hosting their Gradle plugin as well. Since it's only used
>   for Parse Crash Reporting and that feature has been deprecated for
>   almost a year now, I'd say the best option is to remove all traces of
>   Parse Crash Reporting, including the Gradle plugin, from your
>   application.

Now after I changed build script into

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}
```

and removed the rest parts for Parse CrashAnalytics, it works for compilation again.

Thanks muratgu for your hint.